# Net::Twitter::Lite Could not authenticate with OAuth

Tags: perl, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to get a reply for my tweet. I use Net::Twitter::Lite:

```
my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(%consumer_tokens, %access_tokens, legacy_lists_api=>1);
my $mentions = $nt->mentions();
print Dumper $mentions;
```

But after that i have only one error: Could not authenticate with OAuth.
Any ideas?

I can post tweet like: 
`my $status = $nt->update({ status => 'some text' });`
But I can't get the reply.

**UPDATE**

Work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::Twitter::Lite;
use Data::Dumper;

my %consumer_tokens = (
consumer_key    => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
consumer_secret => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
);
my %access_tokens=(
access_token => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
access_token_secret => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
);

my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(%consumer_tokens, %access_tokens, legacy_lists_api=>1);

#217932132083970049
my $status = $nt->update({ status => 'Happy Perl People!' });
print Dumper $status;
```

Don't Work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::Twitter::Lite;
use Data::Dumper;

my %consumer_tokens = (
consumer_key    => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
consumer_secret => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
);
my %access_tokens=(
access_token => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
access_token_secret => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
);

my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(%consumer_tokens, %access_tokens, legacy_lists_api=>1);

#217932132083970049
my $mentions = $nt->mentions();
print Dumper $mentions;
```

Comment: You have to provide more info. What are the `token`-hashes like?

Comment: %consumer_tokens and %access_tokens i get from https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Comment: I cannot open that link because I cannot sign in. Please show how they look like. You can replace actual data with fake stuff.

Answer (score 0):

first it registers the api and generates the information, modifies the script and I list

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Twitter::Lite;

my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(
  consumer_key        => 'key_here', #first 
  consumer_secret     => 'consumer_secret_here', #
  access_token        => 'access_token', #second, generate token 
  access_token_secret =>  'access_token_secret', # 
  legacy_lists_api => 0,
);

my $result = eval { $nt->update('otra prueba') };

warn "$@\n" if $@;
```